# bash resolve aliases and variables

Tags: bash, variables, awk, grep, alias

I have various lines in my profile like this:

```
alias x='ls -al'; alias y='df -kh' # etc
```

I have various lines that define variables:

```
xx='name'; yy='stuff'
```

If I make a typo for an alias and don't put the word `alias` before it, then it will simply define a variable and not generate an error, e.g. `y='df -kh'`.

Is there a way with grep or awk to parse a script to find all definitions that don't have `alias` before them (so that I can determine if they were supposed to be an alias or a variable declaration)? i.e. find anything that looks like a variable that does not have `alias` written before it?

Comment: If you use ShellCheck, it'll complain about unused variables.

Comment: `grep -E '^[A-Za-z0-9_]+=' .bash_profile` but that won't cope with all your examples. A more complex regex could be made to also look for assignments after `;` but a better fix is probably for you to not format your `.bash_profile` with semicolons. In the limit, regex is insufficient for this problem; you need a shell script parser to find all occurrences.

Comment: As far back as 1996, the line stating that aliases are effectively obsolete was present in the bash documentation.  And yet people continue (ab)using them.  Stop using aliases!!  Use functions.

Comment: And yet they are as used today as they were in 1996, and will continue to be used decades into the future. It's just a convenient option, and, if they really wanted them removed, they had hundreds of versions of bash from which they could purge the language of this. I'll use them as they are convenient, and there is no performance issue (that is a commonly/falsely reported myth).

Comment: Thanks @triplee. Using grep -E '[A-Za-z0-9_-]+=' (removing start of line and adding - matches all of what I want, but in addition to that, I would like which of those matched are not prefixed with alias (and a space) so that I can determine any inconsistencies. Is it possible to find only the subset of matches that do not have `alias` before them?

Comment: Pure `grep` not so easily, `grep -P` can do it with a lookbehind, but that's not portable to non-GNU `grep` ... but I would simply use `grep -E '[A-Za-z0-9_]+=' file | grep -v '^alias '` (tangentially there is no way for a symbol to contain a hyphen, so I took that out from your regex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat defs
alias x='ls -al'; alias y='df -kh' # etc
xx='name'; yy='stuff'
```

```
$ cat diffsets
#!/bin/bash

# Restart with a clean environment in case the file has been sourced
# previously. We need the absolute path in the shebang above for this.
[[ -v HOME ]] && exec -c "$0" "$@"

# We must use full paths without variables in case those variables
# are also set in the file we're about to source.
[[ -s "$1" ]] &&
mkdir -p "/usr/tmp/diffsets_$$" &&
trap '
    rm -f "/usr/tmp/diffsets_$$/old" "/usr/tmp/diffsets_$$/new" &&
    rmdir "/usr/tmp/diffsets_$$"
' 0 &&

# We want to only compare variables, not function definitions, but we
# can't use `set -o posix` as we need newlines printed as $'\n' instead
# of literal newline chars for later comparison so ensure posix is disabled
# and use awk to exit when the first function is seen as they always are
# printed after variables.

set +o posix &&
set | awk '$NF=="()"{exit} 1' > "/usr/tmp/diffsets_$$/old" &&

. "$1" &&

set +o posix &&
set | awk '$NF=="()"{exit} 1' > "/usr/tmp/diffsets_$$/new" &&

comm -13 "/usr/tmp/diffsets_$$/old" "/usr/tmp/diffsets_$$/new"
```

```
$ ./diffsets defs
xx=name
yy=stuff
```

I'm specifically not using variables to hold the `set` output for comparison nor using `mktemp` to create the temp files (which would require variables to hold the `mktemp` output) as anything using variables in this script would fail if the file being sourced (`defs` in this case) contained a definition for those variables.